# Beginner javascript hour function

Tags: javascript, function, time, hour

I am very new to javascript and would appreciate some help in understanding this problem.

I am trying to write a function that that checks if the current hour is between hourOne and hourTwo, this is what I have so far:

```
function checkHourBetween (hourOne, hourTwo)
{
var date = new Date();
var currentHour = date.getHours();

if (currentHour >= hourOne && currentHour <= hourTwo)
    {
        return true;
    }

return false;
}
```

And I am trying to call it using:

```
if(checkHourBetween(12, 18))
{
//action
}
```

I have tested this with a simple `document.write("Hello World")` inside the `if` statement just to see if it was working but am getting nothing. My current time is within the specified hours.

I am sure there are better ways to do this (other than javascript) but would love to know where I am going wrong with what I have written.

Comment: It [seems fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/cnDnw/). But note that you [could simplify it a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/cnDnw/1/).

Comment: @ Mathew: It should work just fine. One trick you could use, if you liked, would be to change your function to one line: `return currentHour >= hourOne && currentHour <= hourTwo;` (since that expression evaluates to `true` or `false`, you can just return it directly).

Comment: Try adding `alert(currentHour);` to your function and see what comes up.

Comment: After `var currentHour = date.getHours();` add `console.log(currentHour);` and check the [JavaScript Console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to see if the result is what you're expecting. It could be that `currentHour` isn't between 12 and 18.

Comment: @Mathew Harrington +1 for "this is what I have so far". Except for specific situations, I'd try to avoid document.write() if possible. There are plenty of other ways to insert content with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code as far as I can see, maybe somewhere else in your code is something wrong. Try to run it in FireFox with firebug or with Chrome (no plugin needed) press F12 and check out the console.

```
function checkHourBetween (hourOne, hourTwo)
{
var date = new Date();
var currentHour = date.getHours();
console.log("currenthour is:",currentHour);
console.log("hourOne is:",hourOne);
console.log("hourTwo is:",hourTwo);
if (currentHour >= hourOne && currentHour <= hourTwo)
    {
        console.log("returning true");
        return true;
    }
console.log("returning false");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast responses guys, there was an issue further up that was messing things up. The `console.log` was very useful for debugging, I had not been shown that yet, so thanks again everyone from a javascript newcomer.